# How to parse items from JSON data in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I've a json response like following:

[image]

Now I want to parse the images object and get the `front_image` particularly. I've tried:

```php
//after json_decode($claim)

$front_image = $claim->images->front_image;   // let's say the response is stored in $claim
$front_image = $claim->images[0]->front_image;
```

How can I get all the properties of `images` and store them into different variables?

None of them worked.

Comment: before  that  add $cliam=json_decode($claim);

Comment: ...and after you've done that, you should be able to access it through `$claim->images->front_image;` (and so on for the other images) since `images` is an object, not an array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson.thanks for mentioning erorr

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel but I think you're totally skipping the framework features: [Retrieving JSON Input Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-json-input-values)

Comment: However, you say that you have a `json response` and seem to be showing us the output in your browser console, which suggests that it's in JS you're outputting it? Do a `var_dump($claim);` after your json_decode and show us that output instead. Tbh, the question is very unclear without proper context.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are using Laravel, post your full controller...

Second, please, read the documentation as you do not need `json_decode` ever again... You are not using the framework then...

Your code should be like:

```php
public function show(Request $request)
{
    // After validating input with Validator or FormRequest

    $front_image = $request->input('claim.images.front_image');
    $front_image = $request->input('claim.images.0.front_image');
    // Depends on how your data is structured, maybe you will need a loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get images with php json_decode() function:

```
$claim= json_decode($jsonstring);

print_r($claim->images);
```

Replace $jsonstring with the actual json input.